# Like button in django is not working properly in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have added like and dislike button to Song post When like object is not created if some click on like it is showing intigrity error if like object is already there then it is not rendering that to template.

### models.py

Codes in models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='album_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    singer = models.ManyToManyField(Singer, blank=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class VoteManager(models.Manager):

    def get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(self,song,user):
        try:
            return Vote.objects.get(song=song,user=user)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Vote(song=song,user=user)

class Vote(models.Model):
    UP = 1
    DOWN = -1
    VALUE_CHOICE = ((UP, "️"),(DOWN, "️"),)
    like = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=VALUE_CHOICE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = VoteManager()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'song')
```

### views.py

Codes in views.py

```
class SongDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Song
    template_name = 'song/song_detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(song=self.object, user = self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_url = reverse('music:song_vote_update', kwargs={'song_id':vote.song.id,'pk':vote.id})
            else:
                vote_url = reverse('music:song_vote_create', kwargs={'song_id':vote.song.id})
            vote_form = SongVoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_url'] = vote_url
        return ctx

class SongUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        song = super().get_object(queryset)
        user = self.request.user
        return song
    def get_success_url(self):
        song_id = self.kwargs.get('song_id')
        return reverse('music:song_detail', kwargs={'pk':song_id})

class SongVoteCreateView(View):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    context = {}
    def post(self,request,pk=None,song_id=None):
        vote_obj,created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(pk=pk)
        song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=song_id)
        vote_form = SongVoteForm(request.POST, instance=vote_obj)
        if vote_form.is_valid():
            new_vote = vote_form.save(commit=False)
            new_vote.user = self.request.user
            new_vote.song = song_obj
            return redirect('/album/')
```

### Song_detail.html

codes in song_detail.html

```
        <form action="{{vote_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vote_form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Vote</button>
        </form>
```

### Error Code

This is the error when submitting the like button. [Refer here for the traceback](http://dpaste.com/04EPYEM)

`NOT NULL constraint failed: album_vote.song_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`song` and `user` fields are required. So you have to give `song` and `user` while creating `Vote`.

here is full code::

```
class SongVoteCreateView(View):
    form_class = SongVoteForm
    context = {}
    def post(self,request,pk=None,song_id=None):
        song_obj = Song.objects.get(pk=song_id)
        vote_obj,created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(song = song_obj, user = request.user) 
        vote_form = SongVoteForm(request.POST, instance=vote_obj)
        if vote_form.is_valid():
            vote_form.save()
            return redirect('/album/')
```

also in `VoteManager`, the code

`return Vote(song=song,user=user)`

won't create vote, instead you have to use

`return Vote.objects.create(song=song,user=user)`

Comment: after changing the code the integrity error pointing somewhere else. I will share trace back of that code end of this comment. can please tell what integrity error mens since I am newbee to django I don't know much. traceback : http://dpaste.com/16J60RE

Comment: I think you given null value to `like` field in `Vote` model instead of -1 or 1